# How to embed the terminal from the jupyterhub?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, terminal, jupyter, jupyterhub

I have a web application where I am trying to embed the terminal from the jupyterhub, I hosted it in Azure VM.
I was able to create the terminal, delete the terminal from the token I got from the jupyterhub so now how can I try to access the terminal in my application.

Everywhere I check I am getting only how to get the notebook into the application but for terminal I didn't find any.

I need to perform a sample git operations with pushing the code to the remote repo using the terminal where it is user specific.

Comment: Can you give more details about what you have working now and not working? Code snippets or screenshot?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ChanceSmith I am trying to get the jupyterhub terminal in my application as a iframe so i need to embed that in my application I was not able to embed it.